# drupal Error : call to undefined function Krumo

Tags: drupal, krumo

I'm implementing a block in Drupal to show comments of the user in his/her profile.

I am using `EntityFieldQuery` and `entity_load` and the query works fine. I'm trying to use devel module but I can't see the result by using Krumo function. Any idea what's wrong with my code or how should I use the devel module?

I got this error:

**Fatal Error: call to undefined function Krumo**

```
$items = entity_load('comment', array_keys($result['comment']));
krumo($items);
```

Comment: Do you have `print $messages` in you `page.tpl.php`? Please see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24217/dpm-does-not-display-any-results-on-screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `kpr()` which prints output outside of the template area, or `drupal_debug()` (alias `dd()`) which print variables in a file called `drupal_debug.txt` in the site's temp directory.

Answer (score 1):

Install the devel module and us `dpm($items);`

Comment: I installed devel module. but drupal don't recognize the krumo function. I clear my cache I set all the configuration. I have no idea what was wrong. I unintalled it and install again and it seems everything works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Other Reason can be,

- you need to be logged in as an admin user
- or you need to give "view debug info" permission to your desired role.